# Using django form validation for inlineformset without a POST

Tags: django, forms, validation, inline-formset

In my django app, a user can create a Document model object by either 1) entering data into a form or 2) copying an existing Document. In the second case, I want to use is_valid to confirm that the existing Document is still valid (validity rules may have changed since its creation). I have this working like so:

```
doc = original_doc.clone()
form = DocumentForm(data=doc.__dict__, instance = doc)
if form.is_valid():
    # doc is valid
else:
    ... do stuff ...
```

Now I need to do the same for an inlineformset. Each Document can have 1 or more Item, and I use inline formset for cross-field validation that depends on both a Document field and an Item field. I have this:

```
ItemFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Document, 
              Item, form=ItemForm, formset=CustomItemFormSet)
item_formset = ItemFormSet(data= XXX, instance = doc, 
               queryset=doc.item_set, doc_form=form)
if item_formset.is_valid():
    # item_formset is valid
else:
    ... do stuff...
```

My question is: how do I obtain values for the data parameter (XXX) in the ItemFormSet call? When I display a form to the user, I can use request.POST. Without that, do I need to manually reconstruct the dictionary field by field? It gets complicated due to the data that formsets prepend to the field names, like: 'id_item_set-0-field_name'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies if my question was not straightforward, but I did find a way forward, and will post here in case others find it helpful.

Basically, as far as I found, YES, I do need to manually reconstruct the dictionary field to pass to the ItemFormSet constructor, to create the management form data. Given the single 'item' variable that I wanted to test for validation, I created a dictionary containing item's fields and then added management form data:

```
item_dict = item.__dict__
item_dict_itemset = {}
for key, value in item_dict.iteritems():
    item_dict_itemset["item_set-0-{}".format(key)] = value
item_dict_itemset["item_set-INITIAL_FORMS"] = 0
item_dict_itemset["item_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS"] = 0
item_dict_itemset["item_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS"] = 1000
item_dict_itemset["item_set-TOTAL_FORMS"] = 1

item_formset = ItemFormSet(data-item_dict_itemset, instance=doc, queryset=doc.item_set)
formset_is_valid = item_formset.is_valid()
```